# "Взаимно-однозначный" или "взаимно однозначный"?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

Слово "взаимно-однозначный" присутствует в математике (обычно - взаимно-однозначное преобразование"). Редактор Word подчеркивает его красным, и я, от греха подальше, пишу его раздельно. Но по смыслу хочется написать через дефис. Действительно, это единый термин, свойство отображения. С другой стороны, слитное написание как-то уж слишком громоздко. Что делать?

ЗЫ. Может, вообще перейти на школьную терминологию и писать "обратимый"? Но мне это слово меньше нравится, оно не так информативно. Как хорошо в английском: "one-to-one".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно - биекция. ;)

> > > взаимно однозначный, взаимо однозначный, взаимнооднозначный или взаимооднозначный
>
> Лучше взаимно (взаимооднозначный, причем только в слитном варианте, используется крайне редко и выглядит несколько вычурно), причем слитность/раздельность зависят от наличия определяемого существительного (т.е. от того, выступает ли биективность отношения как самостоятельная семантическая сущность, или служит лишь определением):
> - взаимнооднозначное соответствие;
> - это соответствие - взаимно однозначное.
> Последнее правило действует по крайней мере в моем идиолекте.
> (с) iskander, lingvoforum.net

Я присоединяюсь. С оговоркой, что дефисное написание всё же точнее.

Лопатин: [Взаимно-однозначный](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&word=%E2%E7%E0%E8%EC%ED%EE%EE%E4%ED%EE%E7%ED%E0%F7%ED%FB%E9)

Что качается мнения Брониславы Зиновьевны и Ларисы Павловны, то, думаю, дамы явно неразобрамшись в математике. Речь идет не о том, что однозначность тут взаимная (тогда раздельное написание было бы оправдано), а о т ом, что отношения одновременно **взаимные** и **однозначные**.

Comment: Спасибо, Ваше мнение для меня ценно, так как Вы "в теме". Биекция -это хорошо, но не хочется пугать студентов ...  
Подумав, прихожу к выводу, что все таки однозначность взаимная: отображение однозначно в обе стороны. Но не настаиваю на этой трактовке.

Comment: Суть термина, безусловно, во взаимной однозначности (а не в одновременной взаимности и однозначности). Однозначность отображений "работает" в обе стороны, однозначность взаимна.

Более того, если подумать, математические отношения никогда не могут быть "просто взаимными", вообще, абстрактно; они обязательно должны быть взаимными в каком-то определённом качестве. 

Есть ещё термин "взаимно однозначный гомоморфизм", и вот его все словари дают раздельно.

Comment: >Ваше мнение для меня ценно, так как Вы "в теме".   
  
Не стоит, имхо, заострять. Это не всегда плюс. Потом расскужу, сколько. бывает конфузов именно с теми, кто в теме.

>Биекция -это хорошо, но не хочется пугать студентов ...  
   
one-to-one

Comment: >во взаимной однозначности (а не в одновременной взаимности и однозначности).   
  
Не думаю. Переставьте местами: однозначно-взаимные (только не раздельно). Разве хуже получилось? Части равноправны.  
И потом есть еще косвенное подтверждение. Если есть взаимная однозначность, то должная быть и невзаимная. Однако ни для инъекций, ни для сюръекций никаких подобных русских терминов не предусмотрено.

И еще. Будь оно так было бы скорее всего **взаимо**, как во взаимохаменяемый.

Comment: >Есть ещё термин "взаимно однозначный гомоморфизм", и вот его все словари дают раздельно.  

А вот это еще надо разобраться, что под этим понимают. В принципе морфизм - это отображение на множестве алгебраических систем. Т.е. понятие однозначности несколько другое.

Comment: Однозначно-взаимное - вообще странное выражение. Непонятное абсолютно. Жириновского напоминает! Типа. "Взаимное. Однозначно!"

Comment: @stopkran, с первой частью согласна. Насчет гомоморфизма - странно, так как это просто частный случай отображения (с дополнительным ограничением, а именно, сохраняющий какую-либо структуру). Почему для частного случая отображений написание меняется?

Comment: @DocentI, я придерживаюсь версии, что написание с пробелом - норма, и по это версии написание ни в каких случаях (отображений, отношений...) не меняется. 

Во всяком случае, в Математической энциклопедии это так (я посмотрел там 4 статьи - везде строго "взаимно однозначный"). Вот в одном из Философских словарей - полнейший разнобой (в пределах одной статьи встретилось слитное "взаимнооднозначный" и дефисное "взаимно-однозначный").

Просто в Философском словаре я не нашёл "взаимно однозначного гомоморфизма" - потому и оказался этот пример только с одним вариантом написания! :-)

Comment: @tmp, однозначность в математике вполне может не быть взаимной. Например, в функции y = x * x, каждому аргументу однозначно соответствует результат функции, но не наоборот.

Comment: @stopkran, спасибо за подробное объяснение! По-крайней мере я поняла, что я не одна такая непонятливая, раз даже Философский словарь сомневается! Буду писать раздельно, раз в Математическом словаре так. Да это и приятней: по-крайней мере, не будет противного красного подчеркивания!

Answer (score 2):

В справочнике Слитно или раздельно (Б.Букчина, Л.Калакуцкая, 1982) есть свыше 50 прилагательных с "взаимно". Только два из них даны через дефис: *взаимно-возвратный*  и *взаимно-моторный*. Слово *взаимно однозначный* даётся в раздельном написании, без вариантов.

Слитно или раздельно - самая сложная орфограмма русского языка. В том же справочнике сформулированы некоторые правила. В параграфе 4:

> Пишутся раздельно: Словосочетания,
> состоящие из наречия и прилагательного
> (как правило, качественного) или
> причастия, например: ... взаимно
> дополняющий.

В параграфе 2 есть правило:

> Пишутся слитно: 2. Сложные имена
> прилагательные, образованные из двух и
> более основ, не имеющие в этих основах
> суффиксов прилагательных, например:
> ...товаропассажирский...

То есть, по этой логике, например, слово "взаимооднозначный", следовало бы писать слитно. Так же и "взаимодополняющий".

---

UPD. Кончено, мы не можем игнорировать Орфографический словарь Лопатина (спасибо [[@tmp](/users/1170/tmp)](/users/1170/tmp) за напоминание). Видимо, этот словарь фиксирует более новую норму, формирующуюся под давлением носителей языка - математиков: "в терминах следует использовать дефисное написание" (по аналогии с уже утвердившимися "взаимно-возвратный" и "взаимно-моторный").

Comment: Спасибо, Вы меня успокоили !

Comment: В математике не смыслю, а в Большой р.энциклопедический словарь заглянула(заинтересовало слово). Там раздельно: "Взаимно однозначное соответствие - такое соответствие между элем. 2 множеств, при кот. каждому эл. 1 множества соответствует1 эл. второго множества, а кажд. эл. второго-1 опр. эл. первого множества".В словаре "Слитно или раздельно"тоже раздельное написание.

Comment: Да, это оно, но опять-таки нет понимания, что автор этого определения ориентируется одновременно в принципах математических и орфографических.

Comment: Ну уж этому источнику верить можно. В редакции Большой советской энциклопедии всё на высоком уровне(а это одни и те же люди с данной редакцией).После научного редактора математических терминов проверяют шефы-редакторы, а они работают серьёзно.

Comment: Мдя... Если бы всё было так хорошо...

Comment: Британская энциклопУдия - вечна!

Answer (score 2):

В Математической энциклопедии 1977 года, т. 1: ВЗАИМНО ОДНОЗНАЧНОЕ СООТВЕТСТВИЕ.
В Справочнике по математике (Г.Корн, Т. Корн) 1973 г., стр. 370: ВЗАИМНО ОДНОЗНАЧНОЕ СООТВЕТСТВИЕ.

Answer (score 0):

В математической литературе термин "взаимнооднозначный" ("взаимнооднозначное соответствие") всегда пишется слитно. Никакого пробела и никакого дефиса. Ворд, разумеется, не знает правописания математических терминов. (Вообще, математические тексты лучше набирать в LaTeXе.)

Comment: В добротной математической литературе (в книгах, учебниках, статьях) слитное написание встречается редко. Дефисное ещё реже. На порядок чаще встречается раздельное написание.